# mysql query with where clause containing multiple conditions results in exception during program execusion

Tags: mysql, where-clause, clause

The query below from java is resulting in exception stating that virtual_interfaces.instance_uuid column not found.

The query string is:

```
select instances.id, 
       instances.deleted, 
       instances.project_id, 
       instances.hostname, 
       instances.vm_state, 
       instances.updated_at, 
       instances.uuid, 
       instances.task_state, 
       virtual_interfaces.id, 
       virtual_interfaces.network_id, 
       virtual_interfaces.address, 
       virtual_interfaces.instance_uuid, 
       networks.id, 
       networks.bridge, 
       networks.cidr, 
       networks.vlan, 
       fixed_ips.address, 
       fixed_ips.network_id, 
       fixed_ips.instance_uuid 

from   instances, 
       virtual_interfaces, 
       networks, 
       fixed_ips 

where  instances.uuid=fixed_ips.instance_uuid and
       virtual_interfaces.network_id=networks.id and
       fixed_ips.instance_uuid=virtual_interfaces.instance_uuid;
```

Same query string works if executed fro m the mysql cli.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the query are the same, I mean looking carefully?

Comment: From the query alone can't really tell you much. The virtual_interfaces ddl might help, as would the code in java that builds the query. Chances are it's a minor type as codingbiz says.